# Best Method to transform data between multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

I have a very old system that contains three separate databases.  The tables within these databases are organized very poorly and the system is inefficient because of it.  Our new system requires the data from the old system to be transformed into one new database that has a different schema.

Question
What is the best approach to transform the data between the old system and the new?  Also is there a method to synchronize the data so as people still use the old system the new system will be updated.  This is my first time doing this, so please bare with my poorly worded question.

We are currently using MSSQL 2008 R2 and the new system is moving to MSSQL 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move the data I would suggest using SSIS.  You can build queries that transform the data in the tables to the new tables.  If the schema remains the same you could use SQL Server replication to synchronize them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx.  However, this could lead to some performance issues in practice.

Comment: the tables are very different between the old and new system.  How difficult is SSIS?  Any good tutorials or explanations online?

Comment: SSIS is pretty simple.  There are no tutorials that I could find that relate to your particular need.  In summary you will need to create a new "Integrations Services Project" in Business Intelligence Studio (should have installed with sql server). Create a "Data Flow Task".  Double click the data flow task and create an "OLE DB Source" and "OLE DB Destination".  In the OLE DB source you can point it to your old tables and write a query that will grab your data and the map it to your new table in the odbc source.

Comment: This is an example using a csv file. Instead of a Flat File Source you will want to use an OLE DB Source which you can specify your query in.  This query can go across multiple tables if need be. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/12/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-database-table-using-ssis/